# Find ratio in which F divides AB

Tags: geometry, vectors

In a parallelogram $OABC$ the vectors $\vec 0$, $\vec a$, $\vec b$ and $\vec c$ are respectively the position vectors of the vertices $O$,$A$,$B$ and $C$ respectively.

A point $E$ is taken on the side $BC$ which divides it in the ratio $2:1$.

Also the line segment $AE$ intersects the line bisecting the angle $O$ internally at point $P$.

If $CP$ when extended meets $AB$ in point $F$ then find the ratio in which $F$ divides $AB$.

**My Attempt**

It is easy to get vector equation of line $\vec {AE}$ but I am not able to write vector equation of line $\vec {OP}$

Is there any other way out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are going on a right track. Once you get the position vector of $P$, you are done.

The position vector of $B$ can be written as $$\vec b=\vec a+\vec c\tag 1$$

Also, position vector of $E$ is $$\vec e=\frac{2\vec c+\vec b}{3}=\frac{\vec a+3\vec c}{3}\tag{from 1)(2}$$

Since $P$ lies on angle bisector of $\angle AOC$, $$\vec p=\lambda\left(\frac{\vec a}{|\vec a|}+\frac{\vec c}{|\vec c|}\right)\tag 3$$

Let $P$  divides $EA$  in ratio $μ:1$. Therefore, position vector of $P$ can also be given as $$\vec p=\frac{\mu\vec a+\vec e}{\mu+1}=\frac{(3\mu+1)\vec a+3\vec c}{3(\mu+1)}\tag{from 2)(4}$$

Now, solving $(3)$ and $(4)$ for $\lambda$ and $\mu$, we get $$\lambda=\frac{3|\vec a||\vec c|}{3|\vec c|+2|\vec a|}$$

Now, you have the position vector of $P$ as desired and can proceed further.